# Map OpenID profiles from different providers that belong to a single user

Tags: authentication, openid, socialauth, identity-management

Each time a user logs in to my site via SocialAuth, a new profile is created for him if this is the first time this profile was used. Is there a standard way to map multiple OpenID profiles from different providers that belong to a single user?

For example, if a user logged in to my job board using his Yahoo profile and applied for some jobs, then logged in using Gmail and applied for some more, then realized that he has multiple profiles and must log out and re-login each time to access previous applications and related correspondence, I would like to allow that user to merge his profiles and allow logging in to the merged profile using either one going forward.